# pan image on hover horizontally and vertically

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to **change the background** position of an image **on hover both vertically and horizontally**, however the following code fails to work. Any ideas?

**CSS**:

```
#background-thing{ 
    background: url(http://www.dnitza.com/experiments/fullscreen-pan/stairway.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 scroll; 
    background-size: cover; 
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JQuery**:

```
$('#background-thing').mousemove(function(e){
    var mousePosX = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
    var mousePosY = (e.pageY/$(window).height())*100;
    $('#background-thing').css('backgroundPosition', mousePosX+'%' + mousePosY);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space, and a %

```
$('#background-thing').css('backgroundPosition', mousePosX +'% '+mousePosY+'%');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KtG9g/)

Comment: Looks good :-). Also might want to cache some values: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/9h9Lx/ :-D

Comment: As a sidenote, the height seems to be set to 100%, so it doesn't really pan vertically

Comment: If you reduce the height of the frame to force vertical scrolling, then horizontal scrolling doesn't occur. And if you don't, then horizontal scrolling doesn't scroll all the way to the right. These were fundamental problems with the original approach, but I'm not sure how to solve them.